# How to create a onedrive file downloader in c#

Tags: c#

I try to build an app store but I have a problem with my downloader I try to create a file downloader but it's not working at all !!! 
And my visual still tell me that my app doesn't have any errors on codes !
O think that the problem with the direct link from OneDrive !
Plz help me the code is :

[C#]

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
  webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
 webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url.Text), path.Text ; )

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
  progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Download completed!");
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the `NotWorkingAtAllException` or something else?  see: [Ask] and please take the [tour]

Comment: I don't get anything just don't work !!

Comment: @louaysleman Examples of possible problems: *"When I click the button, nothing happens and no breakpoints are hit." "When it reaches this line, an exception of X type is thrown." "My callback functions are never called."* Just saying "it's not working" doesn't help us or you.

Comment: Sorry for that , when I click the button nothing happens and no breakpoints are hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your url is wrong. If you share a link to your file it looks like:

> [https://onedrive.live.com/**redir**?resid=698A32FCADE8DFDA%2121825](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=698A32FCADE8DFDA%2121825)

You have to replace the `redir` by `download` and it will download the file to your storage location:

```
string path = @"your storage location";
string source = "https://onedrive.live.com/download?resid=698A32FCADE8DFDA%2121825";//right download url
//string source = "https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=698A32FCADE8DFDA%2121825";//wrong download url

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += WebClient_DownloadFileCompleted;
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += WebClient_DownloadProgressChanged;
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(source), path);
```

As an alternative you can simply open this link in your browser and the file will be automatically downloaded to your download directory:

```
Process.Start("https://onedrive.live.com/download?resid=698A32FCADE8DFDA%2121825");
```

Comment: I'll try this !! Thank you